# In a Polymer-based game: how to display an image depending on the total score

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, polymer

I'm building a game using javascript and HTML with the Polymer framework. Currently the user gets points when completing a task. When the round ends the screen shows them the total score.

What I would like to do is show the user an image as a "badge" depending on the total score.

For example:

If the total score is 50 or more (but less than 100) show badge1.png
If the total score is 100 or more (but less than 200) show badge2.png
etc.

The following code handles the scoring system. I've got a div that shows all this info when the round is done. What do I need to add for it to show images depending on the total score? I'm a bit puzzled here, thanks.

```
loadScores: function() {
  var pts = 0;
  try {
    this.allScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game-scores'));
    if (!this.allScores) {
      this.resetScores();
    } else {
      for (var n in this.allScores) {
        pts += this.sumPts(this.allScores[n]);
      }
      this.user.score = pts;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    this.resetScores();
  }
},

computeScore: function() {
  if (this.user) {
    var pts = 0;
    for (var n in this.allScores) {
      pts += this.sumPts(this.allScores[n]);
    }
    this.user.score = pts;
    localStorage.setItem('game-scores', JSON.stringify(this.allScores));
  }
},

resetScores: function() {
  localStorage.removeItem('game-scores');
  if (this.user) {
    this.user.score = 0;
  }
  this.allScores = {};
},

sumPts: function(s) {
  var pts = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    pts += (s[i] || 0);
  }
  return pts;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward. Use the hidden expression for this. First create a badge component that handles the display, e.g.

```
<polymer-element name="badge" attributes="score">
 <image src="/images/badge1.png" hidden?="{{ score < 50 || score > 100 }}" />
 <image src="/images/badge2.png" hidden?="{{ score < 100 || score > 200 }} " />
</polymer-element>
```

Then include your badge component as followed:

```
<badge id="badge" />
```

To update the badge, you just assign the user score to it:

```
this.$.badge.score = this.user.score;
```

Or if you keep it within the data binding then you can also do:

```
<badge score="{{ score }}" />
```

and your main code in your component is something like this:

```
this.score = 163;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Obviously you can also move the badge component directly into your main code, however the whole idea of Polymer and web component is that you componentize your code - so  by doing this extra step you can easily extend your badges later without bloating your main code.

Comment: Thank you! That was pretty straightforward indeed. I've been into Polymer for a few weeks now and I'm always learning something new.